# Expectation of Integral of Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, expectation, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

I'm working through some stochastic analysis problems at the moment and I've come across a problem that is a bit tricky (to me) - does anyone know how to calculate this expecation? I'm not sure what to do with the exponential of the BM and the integral.

$\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}} \bigg( \int_{0}^{t} exp(W_u) du \bigg) $

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Apply Tonelli's (or Fubini's) theorem and use that

$$\mathbb{E}\exp(W_u) = \exp \left( \frac{1}{2} u \right)$$

since $W_u \sim N(0,u)$.

Comment: Are Fubini's theorem hypothesis satisfied here? I mean, is $W_u$ $\Omega \times [0,t]$ integrable

Comment: @andereBen Actually you can apply Tonelli's theorem because everything is non-negative. If you prefer to check that the integral is finite, then you can use the identity which I stated in my answer. (Or do you want to know whether it is jointly measurable...? Brownian motion has continuous sample paths.)

Comment: You're totally right, Tonelli thm here works. But I just wanted to check that $$E[\int_0^t B(u)du] = \int_0^t E[B_u]du$$ where $B_u$ is a standard brownian motion.

Here I need to apply Fubini, and to do it I need to have that $$\int_{\Omega \times [0,t]} |B_u(\omega)|du dP(\omega) $$ is finite. But I don't know how to see this

Comment: @andereBen $\mathbb{E}(|B_u|) = \sqrt{u} \mathbb{E}(|B_1|)<\infty$ (why?) and so $$\int_0^t \mathbb{E}(|B_u|) \, du \leq \mathbb{E}(|B_1|) \int_0^t \sqrt{u} \, du < \infty$$

Comment: $E[|B_u|] = \sqrt{u} E[|B_1|]$ by the scaling property for the Brownian motion. 


Here $E[|B_1|] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |x| \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx$ and is of course finite.

Everything right, now?

By the way, thanks a lot @saz

Comment: @andereBen Yes, that's correct.

Comment: thanks for the feedback! :)